# Modificar const void * en C (SSL_read)

Tags: c

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
   int SSL_read(SSL *ssl, void *buf, int num);
```

Y quisiera modificar el `buf` (Modificar el Header), he probado de varias maneras pero siempre se cuelga el programa o simplemente no funciona.

(La función es de `openssl`)

Comment: ¿Qué tal si indicas cual es el contenido exacto de `buffer`, qué caracteres pretendes eliminar y qué es exactamente lo que has intentado?  `void*` puede almacenar cualquier cosa (por algo es un puntero genérico), así que "_eliminar unos caracteres_" no es algo que proporcione demasiada información.

Comment: Por "quitarle unos caracteres" entiendo que es un `char *`, por qué no pasar el parámetro como un `char *` sin el const? De esa forma puedes modificar el dato contenido en el puntero por valor.

Comment: @NaCl también podría ser una estructura con algún campo tipo `char`, vete tu a saber...

Comment: @eferion Tienes razón, pero en esta pregunta no hay suficientes datos sobre por qué necesitamos un `void *` como parámetro...

Comment: @NaCl ese es el motivo de mi primer comentario jejejeje. De hecho estoy por proponer el cierre de la pregunta hasta que se aclare la misma.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por sus comentarios, Aclaro la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

> quisiera modificar el `buffer`

Entonces no es `const`.

> se cuelga el programa o simplemente no funciona

Parece una descripción clara de [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido). Apuesto que para escribir en el `buffer` has tenido que hacer una conversión del puntero constante a puntero no constante; esto puede provocar comportamiento indefinido, prueba pasar el `buffer` como no constante:

```
int mifuncion(void * buffer){
     /* mas codigo */
}
```

Otra cosa que podría estar sucediendo (y que también provocaría comportamiento indefinido) es que te pases de rosca escribiendo en el `buffer`, veo que `mifuncion` no recibe parámetro de tamaño así que si le estás pasando un puntero que apunta a un búfer de tamaño X pero escribes Y (siendo Y > X) podrías tener este problema, para solucionarlo indica cuál es el límite de escritura:

```
int mifuncion(void * buffer, int tamanyo_buffer){
     /* mas codigo */
}
```

Y usa el parámetro `tamanyo_buffer` para escribir como máximo, esa cantidad de bytes.

Pero eso tampoco ayuda, porque el tipo `void` no tiene tamaño y en consecuencia no se puede hacer aritmética de punteros con el mismo, así que apuesto a que además de transformar `bufer` para que no sea constante, deberás transformarlo a un tipo con tamaño

```
int mifuncion(void * buffer, int tamanyo_buffer){
    char *inicio = (char *)buffer;
    /* mas codigo usando inicio en lugar de buffer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu programa crashea seguramente porque estás pasando  un literal de cadena a tu función:

```
mifuncion("hola");
```

La cadena `hola`  se guarda en la región de memoria constante del programa, que es una región de tu ejecutable protegido por el sistema operativo como de solo lectura. Si cualquier cosa que provenga de esa región intenta ser modificado, crashea. De ahí que los castings para quitarle `const` a algo son tan peligrosos. Sólo son seguros si conoces el origen de los datos recibidos (y una función libre nunca debería saberlos).

Tu única solución es que la función reciba la cadena como no constante, y si necesitas pasar una cadena constante (un literal de cadena), haz antes una copia.

```
char buff[espacio_suficiente];
// copiar hola en buff con strcpy o memcpy

mifuncion(buff);
```